# Is it bad to have private static fields in Util classes?

Tags: java, access-modifiers

Let's say that i have a method in a util class that has a parameter that can't be changed in the method because it would change the result and needs to be saved in some way, would it be a bad practice to have a `private static` field inside of the util class? if yes how to do it correctly.

I mean something like that:

```java
public class Util {

    private static final int[] vector1Backup = new int[3];
    private static final int[] vector2Backup = new int[3];

    private Util() {
    }

    public static void doOperation(int[] vector1, int[] vector2, int[] result){

        // backups needed for the case that vecto1 or vector2 = result
        vector1Backup[0] = vector1[0];
        vector1Backup[1] = vector1[1];
        vector1Backup[2] = vector1[2];

        vector2Backup[0] = vector2[0];
        vector2Backup[1] = vector2[1];
        vector2Backup[2] = vector2[2];

        result[0] = vector1Backup[0] + vector2Backup[2];
        result[1] = vector1Backup[1] + vector2Backup[1];
        result[2] = vector1Backup[2] + vector2Backup[0];
    }

}
```

EDIT: Only one thread exists

Comment: What would happen if two threads call the method `doOperation` at the same time?

Comment: @KevinO I think a better question is, what *wouldn't* happen? :P

Comment: Why not just define the backup arrays locally?

Comment: Yes it's bad. Util classes shouldn't keep state. Handle everything in a single method or build a _calculator_ object where you can do the calculation(s) for only single usage (create object, do calculations, destroy object).

Comment: You will probably want to use [`Arrays.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-int:A-int-).

Comment: @JasperHuzen wouldnt this be too ram intesive?

Comment: Private static _final_ fields that you don't modify are fine.  Private static mutable fields are a major code smell.

Comment: As long as its single-threaded and your fields are used as temporary structures for calculations, I don't see a problem with it. There are other libraries that work the same way. For example LibGDX. It uses temporary vectors and matrices for calculating things to prevent too many instantiations.

Comment: @Blacknick not in the slightest, in general.

Comment: One day in the future, you might want your application to be multi-threaded.  When that happens, you don't want to be going through your entire application fixing up things that you've assumed will only ever be single threaded.  Always write code assuming that it needs to be multi-threaded.

Comment: Static *state* is the problem.

Comment: @Blacknick depends on the situation. The number of calculation, the size of the data, the number of calculations on the same data...and so on is important to choose the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it’s not a bad practice to have private constants. It’s fine to hide internals of a class, in OOP we call it encapsulation. However I feel like your code should be changed a bit.

1) Personally I’m against static methods at all, imho they do not follow OOP and make testing harder. However bunch of libraries and java itself has bunch of them. So it’s matter of taste, I guess. And if you like static methods, you should do them stateless, which means do not store anything inside the class, just create result based on vector1 and vector2 and return it from the method.

2) Storing something in static class is kind of error prone. I would just create separate class and call it VectorBackup. In that class I would store vector like you are doing. Then you can create whatever number of instances(backups) is required. It would be thread safe ( to certain extent ) and more OOP like. Also it would be easier to change your code in case if you will have 3 vectors instead of 2.

3) Constant classes should have private constructor and they should be `final`, so no one can extend them.

```
public final class Util {

    private Util() {
    }

    public static void doOperation(int[] vector1, int[] vector2) {
        int[] result = new int[3];
        result[0] = vector1[0] + vector2[2];
        result[1] = vector1[1] + vector2[1];
        result[2] = vector1[2] + vector2[0];
        return result;
    }

}


public class Backup {

    private final int[] vectorBackup = new int[3];

    public Backup(int[] vector) {
        vectorBackup[0] = vector[0];
        vectorBackup[1] = vector[1];
        vectorBackup[2] = vector[2];
    }

    public int[] restore(){
     //some code to create vector from backup
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bad practice to have private constants.

But in your case, you have a private field like a buffer. Plus you make so-called in-place operation, changing the value of `result` array.

If I were you, I'd create a function which returns a result

```
int[] doOperation(int[] vector1, int[] vector2){
  int[] result = new int[vector1.length];
  // do your logic
  return result;
}
```